# Check if link exists

Tags: php, phpbb

I have a phpBB forum on my localhost for learning purposes..now I'm trying to do this using PHP :

When a link gets posted,a script checks if the exact link exists and if it does then the process of posting the message doesn't continue.
EDIT: This is what I have in includes/message_parser.php

```
function url_exists($url) {
$handle = @fopen($url, "r");
if ($handle === false){
return false;
fclose($handle);}
else{
return true;
fclose($handle);}}
```

And this is what I have in posting.php

```
$your_url = "http://www.somewhere.com/index.php";

$your_url = preg_replace(array('#&\#46;#','#&\#58;#','/\[(.*?)\]/'), array('.',':',''), $your_url);

if (url_exists($your_url))
{
echo 'yeah, its reachable';
}
else
{
echo 'what da hell..';
}
```

It works. I can see it echoing what da hell when I post a link that exists,but the problem is that the post gets posted. what I want now is,if the link exists,then don't allow the post to be posted.

2ND EDIT:

```
if($submit){
    $URL = "http://www.fileserve.com/file/rP59FZ2";
    preg_replace(array('#&\#46;#','#&\#58;#','/\[(.*?)\]/'), array('.',':',''), $url);
if(url_exists($url)) {
    echo "Link exists!";
}
```

That's what I did to prevent submitting the topic when the url exists. not working :\

Comment: Define "exists". Also, this is not http://give-me-teh-codez.com

Comment: You still don't block the submit. you could try and put exit() after your echo, and see if it blocks. Also, properly because of copy-paste code, but you're missing a closing bracket } at the end.

Comment: I tried the exit(); before you suggested it,and it didn't work. no idea guys! :\

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checking if link return status code 200 (dunno about 30x)

Using cURL:

```
function url_exists($url) {
    $ch = @curl_init($url);
    @curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);
    @curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, TRUE);
    @curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, FALSE);
    @curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    $status = array();
    preg_match('/HTTP\/.* ([0-9]+) .*/', @curl_exec($ch) , $status);
     return ($status[1] == 200);
}
// now call the function
$myUrl = "http://www.somewhere.com";
if(url_exists($myUrl)) {
    echo "Link exists!";
} else {
    echo "Link does not exist :(";
}
```

Without cURL:

```
function url_exists($url) {
    $h = get_headers($url);
    $status = array();
    preg_match('/HTTP\/.* ([0-9]+) .*/', $h[0] , $status);
    return ($status[1] == 200);
}
// now call the function
$myUrl = "http://www.somewhere.com";
if(url_exists($myUrl)) {
    echo "Link exists!";
} else {
    echo "Link does not exist :(";
}
```

You can play around with it :)

**UPDATE**

To the updated question.

I don't know exactly how phpBB works or where you're trying to catch it, but some suggestions to stop the posting might be to check for the link using javascript/jQuery and then disable the submit button alerting/printing a statement as to why the post wasn't posted.

I'm not that into regex and such, but you would check the post if it contains any link you where looking for, and then "block" the submit of the form.

Something along the lines of:

```
$('#myform').submit(function(event){
    // disable the submit button so the user doesn't spam it
    $('#myform input[type=submit]', this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');

    // check with regex for the links
    // if it's found return true else return false to variable preventSubmit
    if(preventSubmit) {
        // prevent the form from being submitted
        event.preventDefault();
        // notify the user
        alert("You cannot post that link!");
        return false;
    }

});
```

as extra security, you could disable the submit by default, and only enable it once the javascript has loaded.

Comment: @wadie , you need to pass an url into the function.
Like this:
`url_exists("http://www.somewhere.com");`
Or:
`$url = "http://www.somewhere.com";
url_exists($url);`

Comment: @wadie I have edited the example to give a more complete example of it's use :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit heh, thanks. At work and had to hurry a bit so didn't pay much attention to grammar :)

Comment: Not getting any errors now,but still not doing anything new when posting. maybe I'm doing something wrong with phpBB ?

Comment: @wadie reading your comments to O.D's solution, I think you misguided us a bit in what you're actually trying to achieve. You wrote "I want a function which only checks if the exact url has been posted before." I suggest revising the question to match this :) Right now, you're just asking on who to check if a linke "exists", which means returns 200 for us.

Comment: OK,sorry for the confusion. I edited the question with the code I have,and with what I need to achieve. Thanks! :)

Comment: Thanks for your help.
I found that the submit variabl is $submit = (isset($_POST)); 
so i thought about doing this: (added on first post)

Answer (score 0):

First check to see whether the link format is valid:

```
function isValidURL($url) {
  return preg_match('|^http(s)?://[a-z0-9-]+(.[a-z0-9-]+)*(:[0-9]+)?(/.*)?$|i', $url);
}
```

Then make sure the resource that the link refers to actually exists:

```
function checkLink() {
   $handle = fopen("http://www.example.com/", "r");
   if ($handle) { fclose($handle); return true; }
   return false;
}
```

Comment: and what if I want to check if the domain+url path already exists ? like http://domain.com/filename (filename is dynamic)

Comment: replace in the second function `http://www.example.com/` with the link you want. Eg: `http://www.example.com/path/to/any/file/or/page.html`

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
$url = 'http://www.anyURL.com';
$hndl = @fopen($url,'r');
if($hndl !== false){
   echo 'URL Exists';
}
else
{
   echo "URL Doesn't exist";
}
```

Comment: I knew that already. but I think I need another variable,cause the link is going to be like http://filehost/FileName and I don't want to the post to continue if the filename exists and not the domain!

Comment: then use the file_exists function, and break using "break;" if the filename And/Or URL doesnt exists or not valid

Comment: hmm the files aren't on the server

Comment: if you have the needed access rights you still can access a file.

Comment: I don't have access.
maybe I didn't make myself clear to what I really need.
I want a function which only checks if the exact url has been posted before. I think it can also be dealt with as text..if that text has been posted before (which is formed as a url),then don't post.

Comment: Ok, then how about you use the "strpos($TheForumPage, $NewURL);"